# Angular 2 attribute directive - inputs are undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create an attribute directive that will catch click events and report them to our reporting service. I've followed the [attribute directives guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) and ended up with this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[mtTrack]'
})
export class MtTrackDirective {

    private _eventData: any;

    constructor(private trackingService: TrackingService) {}

    @Input('mtTrack') eventName: string;

    @Input('mtTrackEvent') set mtTrackEvent(data: any) {
        this._eventData = data;
    }

    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
        this.trackingService.track(this.eventName, this._eventData)
    }
}
```

I then try to test it with this test:

```
describe('MatificTrackDirective', () => {
    @Component({
        selector: 'test-cmp',
        template: `<div [mtTrack]="'fakeEvent'" [mtTrackEvent]="{test: 'fake data'}"></div>`,
        viewProviders: [MatificTrackDirective]
    })
    class TestComponent {}

    let trackingMock;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let debugElement : DebugElement;
    let hostComp;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent, MatificTrackDirective],
            providers: [{provide: TrackingService, useValue: mockClass(TrackingService)}]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        hostComp = fixture.componentInstance;
        debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatificTrackDirective));
        trackingMock = debugElement.injector.get(TrackingService)
    })
    describe("HANDLERS", () => {
        describe("onclick", () => {
            When(() => {
                debugElement.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
                fixture.detectChanges();
            });
            Then(() => expect(trackingMock.track).toHaveBeenCalledWith('fakeEvent', {test: 'fake data'}));
        });
    });
});
```

But my `trackingMock` is being called with `[undefined, undefined]` instead of the values in the template. Any idea what is wrong?

I'm using Angular 2.2.1.

Comment: Did you add `MtTrackDirective` to `declarations: [...]` in `@NgModule(...)`? Did you check if it is instantiated at all by adding `console.log('MtTrackDirective');` to the constructor for example?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've only tried to test it in a test contest, so there's not `NgModule` beside what the `TestBed` creates. The constructor is being called in the test.